Correctness of an algorithm for three-way disjointness problem
The problem is to decide if three nonempty sets of integers, represented as three arrays A, B and C (Python lists in the code below), have empty intersection.
I have written the following Python code implementing a decision algorithm for this problem:
def disjoint(A, B, C):
    """Solves (?) three-way disjointness problem in n*log(n) time.
    """

    A = sorted(A[:])
    B = sorted(B[:])
    C = sorted(C[:])

    i = j = k = 0
    while i < len(A) and j < len(B) and k < len(C) and (A[i] != B[j] or B[j] != C[k]):
        if A[i] <= B[j] and A[i] <= C[k]:
            i += 1
        elif B[j] <= A[i] and B[j] <= C[k]:
            j += 1
        else:
            k += 1

    if i < len(A) and j < len(B) and k < len(C):
        return False
    else:
        return True

The algorithm seems to be correct (intuitive idea seems ok, and it does ok in the concrete tests), however I can't prove it formally.
So the question is: how to prove the above algorithm correct? What is a good, working loop invariant for the proof?
(Or, if it is not correct, a counterexample. Note that Python here is irrelevant, I could have written it in pseudo-code. I'm interested in quasi-formal argument for this algorithm's correctness.)
(I tried to produce a formal proof myself; I have tested this idea by a practical implementation and it seems to work.)

This question looks familiar.

Prove by stating the loop invariant: the lists up to i,j,k are disjoint (trivially true at start).  Then show that each iteration leaves the statement true.

This is where the problem lies for me: I am unable to give a convincing argument that if we know that all lists up to (excluding) i, j, k are disjoint; and the loop condition evaluates to True, than after incrementing the smallest of i, j, k by one all list up to (modified) i, j, k are still disjoint. A convincing (quasi)formal argument that this is the case still eludes me.

The algorithm is correct.  A loop invariant that works is Any common element must be >= max(A[i], B[j], C[k]).
From that, it's easy to show that i, j, or k, is only incremented when it points to a value that is too low, and that the invariant still holds after the increment, because the sort guarantees that there are no possible common elements between the old and new values.
As often happens, the correctness proof allows you to simplify your code, because you don't have to find the smallest of the 3 elements, just one that is smaller than the max:
def disjoint(A, B, C):
    """Solves (?) three-way disjointness problem in n*log(n) time.
    """

    A = sorted(A[:])
    B = sorted(B[:])
    C = sorted(C[:])

    i = j = k = 0
    while i < len(A) and j < len(B) and k < len(C):
        m = max(A[i], B[j], C[k])
        if A[i] < m:
            i += 1
        elif B[j] < m:
            j += 1
        elif C[k] < m:
            k += 1
        else
            return False
    return True


Thank you for your answer and a nice loop invariant.

After reading your answer I have also produced a convincing, even if somewhat informal, proof: first note that if the loop condition is satisfied, then exactly one of i, j, k will be incremented by one. If there is no common element, then clearly the loop terminates with one index being out of bounds, and the algorithm correctly decides that we have three-way disjointness. Now suppose that there is some common element. Let's consider the smallest one among common elements. At some point during the loop execution one of the indices will become the index of that smallest element in one of

the lists. Say (wlog) the first one to get to that common element is i. Now, in subsequent iterations, and thanks to the fact that lists are sorted, i will not be incremented, but j and k will untill one of them reaches the common element in other list (since we move an index not pointing to largest element). Then the index that is left will be incremented untill it reaches our common element, at which point the loop terminates. The algorithm then correctly decides that lists are not three-way disjoint.

The following proof uses the following notation:
{X} is a set with one element X,
+ is union,
* is intersection.
Let the nonempty sets A,B,C are splitted into subsets:
A = {A0} + A1,  {A0} * A1 = 0
B = {B0} + B1,  {B0} * B1 = 0
C = {C0} + C1,  {C0} * C1 = 0

where A0,B0,C0 are the first elements (lower bounds) of A,B,C.
{A0} * {B0} != 0 only if A0 == B0 and so on.
The intersection of A,B,C is
A * B * C = S0 + Sa + Sb + Sc 
S0 = {A0} * {B0} * {C0}
Sa = {A0} * ({B0} * C1 + B1 * {C0} + B1 * C1) + A1 * ({B0} * {C0} + {B0} * C1 + B1 * {C0} + B1 * C1)
Sb = {B0} * ({A0} * C1 + A1 * {C0} + A1 * C1) + B1 * ({A0} * {C0} + {A0} * C1 + A1 * {C0} + A1 * C1)
Sc = {C0} * ({A0} * B1 + A1 * {B0} + A1 * B1) + C1 * ({A0} * {B0} + {A0} * B1 + A1 * {B0} + A1 * B1)

If S0 != 0 then the sets are not disjoint.
It's obviosly that if A0 ≤ B0 then {A0} * B1 == 0 and so on.
Let A0 ≤ B0 and A0 ≤ C0 then
Sa = A1 * ({B0} * {C0} + {B0} * C1 + B1 * {C0} + B1 * C1)
Sb = {B0} * (A1 * {C0} + A1 * C1) + B1 * (A1 * {C0} + A1 * C1)
Sc = {C0} * (A1 * {B0} + A1 * B1) + C1 * (A1 * {B0} + A1 * B1)

Since A0 is completely removed from Sa, Sb and Sc, {A0} can also be subtracted from A, and A * B * C can still be used to determine disjointness.
B0 can be removed from B in case of B0 ≤ A0 and B0 ≤ C0. And the same for C.
If any modified set became empty then the sets are disjoint since A * B * C == 0. In other case the next iteration is required.
